# In IntelliJ Idea my app works, but as a jar -- not because of "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea

I have java 1.7 installed. In IntelliJ Idea my app works, but when I run it as a `jar`, it returns an error:

```
$ java -jar my_app.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class my_app.MyMainClass
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you share your jar's manifest?

Comment: Could you explain the way you create that jar?

Comment: Please read this guide to asking questions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @CrazyPython, no, you read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an executable jar.  See this page, *Setting an Application's Entry Point*, for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

Either declare main class in the my_app.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as described in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

```
Main-Class: full.class.Name
```

Or start your application in a different way:

```
java -classpath my_app.jar full.class.Name
```